# Using repeat() and times() to create multiple edges at once

Tags: gremlin

How do I use the times() Step on my repeat(..) to create multiple, identical edges at once?

```
g.V().has('Label1', 'id', '1234').repeat(addE('HAS').from(g.V().has('Label2', 'id', '5678'))).times(5)
```

I would think that it adds my edge 5 times to this vertex, in fact it returns nothing when times() is great than 1. Why is that and how would I use repeat() correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what graph database you are using, but I'm somewhat surprised you don't get an error with that bit of Gremlin and that error should yield a hint as to what is wrong.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').repeat(addE('knows').from(V().has('person','name','stephen'))).times(5)
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerEdge cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

The `repeat()` step is not meant to simply execute the same child traversal with the same input for each iteration. It is meant to execute the same child traversal with the output of the previous iteration as the new input. That means on the first iteration we initialize that child traversal of:

```
addE('knows').from(V().has('person','name','stephen'))
```

with the "marko" vertex, but the output of that traversal is an `Edge` (because the output of `addE()` is an `Edge`). On the second iteration that edge becomes the input to `addE()` and therefore....error....as you can't call `addE()` on an edge.

If you want to use `repeat()` for this type of flow control you can though, but you need to arrange the child traversal so that the input is that same initial vertex on each iteration:

```
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name','marko').addV('person').property('name','stephen').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').as('m').
......1>   V().has('person','name','stephen').as('s').
......2>   repeat(select('m').addE('knows').to('s')).
......3>     times(3).iterate()
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[4][0-knows->2]
==>e[5][0-knows->2]
==>e[6][0-knows->2]
```

Comment: I had a fundamental misunderstanding of repeat(), thank you! I am using apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.4.1 but there was no output at all when running this false query.